# Sum a column in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I am working with SSRS 2008. I am trying to get a sum of a column. I taking the top 5 defects and summing up how many times they happened. I used the expression =Sum(Fields!Defect.Value) but it just comes back with an error messag. Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: What is the data type of the column you are trying to SUM?

Comment: I am group types of defects

Comment: That doesn't answer what the data type is.  I am looking for string, integer, decimal, etc.  The reason being is most people think it is a number so they SUM it when it is in fact a string.  You could need to CInt then SUM in order for it to work correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you shound't be using `SUM` but `COUNT`, but we can't really tell from your question

Comment: I have tried doing a count. Im just a beginner with SSRs 2008. Please tell me what i need to provide to get the best of help from you.

Comment: If you run the report in Visual Studio it should give you the actual error message in the output window. (Instead of just getting #Error)